# Round Decimals and Update in same MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, double, decimal

I have an MySQL table like this:
`-------------------------------------------`
`|ID  | Name  | Value                      |`
`| 1  | Jack  | 1.0382948092380932980293   |`
`| 2  | John  | 12.3489245802843509384001  |`
`| 3  | Bill  | 6.0293892838236487263872   |`
`-------------------------------------------`

I want to update Values to three-digit decimal number after the comma like the scheme below.
`------------------------`
`|ID  | Name  | Value   |`
`| 1  | Jack  | 1.038   |`
`| 2  | John  | 12.348  |`
`| 3  | Bill  | 6.029   |`
`------------------------`

How can I do this using MySQL sentence? Thank you.

Comment: Will this one work? "update table set value=round(value, 3)" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `round`:

```
update tablename set fieldname = round(fieldname,3)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to update the values with the new values in the table.

Comment: And here is documentation for this http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-round-function.php

Answer (score 0):

You want to round up the value use jherran answer,
But I think you want to round down the value, so you should use: `truncate` function

```
update tablename set fieldname = truncate(fieldname ,3)
```

refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69548823