# SQL how to round down an integer value to 2 decimal places

Tags: mysql, sql, grafana

I am trying to perform a SQL query which pulls a value to 2 decimal places as depicted below. The issue is the value is actually 8.498, where it is outputted as 8.50 and I need it in my case to be outputted at 8.49 instead.
[image: Dashboard Output]

This is my current code below, is there a way that I can use FLOOR to output the value as 8.49

```
SELECT gas_date as 'time', provisional_price
from INT654
where provisional_price  is not null AND hub_name = 'Sydney' AND provisional_schedule_type = 'D-2'
order by gas_date desc limit 1
```

Comment: `ROUND(FLOOR(8.498 * 100) / 100, 2)`

Comment: The fact you want to do this with a money value almost certainly means you have an XY problem....

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to round down, you have to do:

```
floor(provisional_price*100)*.01
```

But if you really want to round towards zero (down for positives, up for negatives), you can do:

```
truncate(provisional_price,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to truncate to two decimals rather than rounding off, you can use ROUND function and send 3rd argument as anything other than 0.

> ROUND ( provisional_price , 2 , 1 )

Official documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms175003(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN